# Challenging Big O

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have a problem with the Big O:

```
for i:=1 to n do
for j:=1 to i*i do 
begin
  k:=1; m:=n;
  while m>=k do 
  begin
    k:=k*3;
    m:=m/2
  end
end
```

Teacher gave the answer - n*n*n*log(n). However, I can't get there. That is supposed to be log for the basis 2. Please help.

Comment: Do you understand any part of the answer?

Answer (score 4):

Here you see where the parts come from:

```
for i:=1 to n do      <-- n
for j:=1 to i*i do    <-- n*n
begin
  k:=1; m:=n;
  while m>=k do       <-- log(n)
  begin                    /
    k:=k*3;               /
    m:=m/2            <--+
  end
end
```

the loops are nested so you multiply their complexities

To understand the base 2 log, let's start with a simpler example:

```
  while m>=k do
  begin
    k:=k*2;
    m:=m/2
  end
```

this loop runs exactly `⌈(log n)/2⌉` times (base 2) because simply spoken m and k meet in the middle (not the exact middle of course!) after half of the time. The constant factor `0.5` is ignored in Big-O.
For `k:=k*3`the case is similar, but the result will be between `(log n)/2` (base 3) and `(log n)/2` (base 2).
I'll leave the math up to you, but you will understand that `m:=m/2` has more significance because it starts from top to bottom.

Comment: I don't understand how come that while has log(n) complexity. The problem is "k:=k*3;". It seems to me that the complexity is log(n),but for the basis of 6!

Comment: Because `log_b(n)`
 to the basis `b`
 is equal to `log_b(2^log(n)) = log_b(b^(log_b(2)))^log(n)) = log_b(b^(log_b(2))*log(n)) = log_b(2)*log(n)`
 and `log_b(2)`
 is a constant factor which can be ignored in big-O

Comment: @BeniBela: great explanation why the base does not matter in big-O. I edited the answer with a less mathematical explanation but I just realized, that was quite unnecessary :)